# Replacing zero values in table A with non-zero values in table B if available

Tags: r

I have data as follows:

```
tableA <- structure(c(0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L), dim = c(3L, 
3L), dimnames = structure(list(c("0.3", "0.4", 
"0.6"), c("A", "B", "C")), names = c("", "")), class = "table")

      A B C
  0.3 0 0 3
  0.4 0 6 0
  0.6 6 0 0

tableB <-structure(c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L), dim = c(3L, 
3L), dimnames = structure(list(c("0.3", "0.4", 
"0.6"), c("A", "B", "C")), names = c("", "")), class = "table")

      A B C
  0.3 0 0 3
  0.4 1 3 2
  0.6 2 0 0
```

I would like to replace all zeroes in `tableA` with positive values in `tableB` if they are available and somehow mark them.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Desired output:

```
      A B C
  0.3 0 0 3
  0.4 1 6 2
  0.6 6 0 0
```

The added issue is that I would somehow like to know which values were replaced, but that seems difficult to realise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a logical index based on the 0 values in `tableA` with `==` and the positive values (`> 0`) from `tableB` and do the assignment

```
i1 <- tableA == 0 & tableB > 0
tableA[i1] <- tableB[i1]
```

-output

```
> tableA
     
      A B C
  0.3 0 0 3
  0.4 1 6 2
  0.6 6 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `!tableA` as a mask like below

```
> (!tableA) * tableB + tableA

      A B C
  0.3 0 0 3
  0.4 1 6 2
  0.6 6 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
ifelse(tableA == 0, pmax(tableB,0), tableA)

#>      
#>       A B C
#>   0.3 0 0 3
#>   0.4 1 6 2
#>   0.6 6 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach

```
ifelse(tableA == 0 & tableB > 0 , tableB , tableA)
```